# AngularJS - resolve value is defined in ui-router, but in controller is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have resolve in my route where I return value, which is defined when I console.log it, but in controller it is undefined... I am newbie in Angular and Ionic.

## Route

```
.state('tab.item', {
url: '/collections/item/:itemId',
views: {
  'tab-collections': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-item.html',
    controller: 'ItemCtrl',
    resolve: {
      item: function($localStorage, $stateParams){
        angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(value, key){
          if (value.id == $stateParams.itemId){
            console.log(value);
            return value;
          }
        });
      },
    }
  }
}
```

## Controller

```
.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, item) {
    $scope.item = item;
    console.log(item);
})
```

## View

```
<ion-view view-title="{{item.name}}">
    <ion-content>
        {{item}}
        <div>
             <li ng-repeat="image in item.images">
                 <img ng-src="{{image}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
             </li>
        </div>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

## So why it was working in here?

```
collection: function($localStorage, $stateParams){
    angular.forEach($localStorage.collection, function(value, key){
       if (value.id == $stateParams.collectionId){
          return value;
       }
    });
 },
```

Comment: this wouldnt ever work afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve needs you to return a value. You have your return inside of the forEach loop. In order for this to work you will need to return outside of that loop. Perhaps something like:

```
.state('tab.item', {
url: '/collections/item/:itemId',
views: {
  'tab-collections': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-item.html',
    controller: 'ItemCtrl',
    resolve: {
      item: function($localStorage, $stateParams){
        var result;
        angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(value, key){
          if (value.id == $stateParams.itemId && !result){
            console.log(value);
            result = value;
          }
        });
        // return outside of the loop
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might also consider using something other than forEach here since you cannot break out of the loop early. A basic for loop would work just as well.

Comment: Accept for advice with basic loop

Answer (score 1):

you aren't returning a value in your resolve function, returning in a foreach does not do what you think :)

```
.state('tab.item', {
    url: '/collections/item/:itemId',
    views: {
      'tab-collections': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-item.html',
        controller: 'ItemCtrl',
        resolve: {
          item: function($localStorage, $stateParams){
            var valueToReturn;
            angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(value, key){
              if (value.id == $stateParams.itemId){
                console.log(value);
                valueToReturn = value;
              }
            });
            return valueToReturn
          },
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Weird thing is that it worked in one route before... `collection: function($localStorage, $stateParams){
            angular.forEach($localStorage.collection, function(value, key){
              if (value.id == $stateParams.collectionId){
                return value;
              }
            });
          },`

Comment: doesnt do anything in this case. in a `map` function it would be the new items of an array